# Cakephp i18n, how exclude by default the plugin folder?

Tags: cakephp, internationalization

I am using cake i18n,
when it creates the file default.pot there are also strings of the plugin.
How make to exclude the folder plugin from cake i18n?

Answer (score 3):

The good solution will be [using __d() function with prefix of name of plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#internationalizing-cakephp-plugins).

or

In CakePHP i18n shell You can [exclude folders](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html#excluding-folders).

Comment: +1 though the answer shouldn't only be references, example usage (opr a brief but relevant explanation) with example output would suffice.